# When to use Instruction Set Extensions Technology from Intel

Tags: c++, intel, sse, simd, avx

When does it make sense to use Instruction Set Extensions Technology from Intel and what exactly does it do?

**My scenario:** I want to do ~500.000 matrix vector multiplications as fast as possible.

matrix size: [4x4] | vector size: [1x4]

Comment: It makes sense any time you need performance and you can control / know what machines your code will run on.  e.g. on your home desktop, or on a specific set of servers, compile with `gcc -O3 -march=native`.  Or if you really need performance, then even runtime CPU dispatching can be worth it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info.

Comment: Fortunately for matmul, you don't need to do a lot of manual work, just use an optimized BLAS library.  Unless your matrices are tiny or very odd shaped, then custom code could help.  (Although Eigen, being a C++ template library, can take advantage of known stuff at compile time.)

Comment: You could think of using one or more GPUs for this. Although that's a whole new word (of hurt).

Comment: 500000 matrix vector products of different sizes? Or all of the same (possibly small) size? Can you do them in parallel? Do they share the same matrix or vector?

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee your clients have a certain level of SIMD support I don't see what's holding you back.

SIMD has been around for a long enough time it's not unreasonable to require your clients to have it.

As an example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-x86?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-x64?view=vs-2019

x86-64 guarantees that SSE2 is available, so compilers *always* use that for 64-bit builds.  (And in some sense it's not an extension anymore, just a baseline part of the x86-64 ISA).

EDIT:

Thank you for the edit Peter Cordes!

But I also wanted to point out to users if they are interested in SIMD they might want to look into OpenCL.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL

OpenCL helps users write very efficient SIMD programs.

Comment: All Amd64 compilers should use SSE2 as all AMD64 processors have a minimum of SSE2 support